# Scalable background images aligned horizontally one after the other

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I'm building a custom horizontal slideshow and I've idealized one with full scalable images - as you resize the browser window, the images scale accordingly.

Now, for this to happen, I need to have a `position: fixed` on my images div container - according to this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

I used the CSS-Only Technique #1:

```
#imageContainerDiv img {
    min-height: 100%; 
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

So, what I need is for the images to align themselves horizontally one after the other (like with float).
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZecHS/) (no buttons).
Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: Is it a problem that your images get skewed?

Comment: No, the scale is ok. Just need them to be side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the images within the container to display:inline-block and setting the dimensions to the container itself. You may also need to set the container itself to display:table. Something like this:

```
#imageContainerDiv {
    display:table;
    min-width: 1024px;
    height:auto;
}

#imageContainer Div img {
   display:inline-block;
   width: 100%; 
   height: auto;
   position: fixed; 
   top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope, apparently that's not enough.